# How to solve this for-loop exercise in c++ (beginner). n + nx2 + nx2x2 +

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was trying to write a c++ programm, which  begins with int a - 5 items, and every second int b - gets bigger 2x times. For example 1second prints - 5, 2second - 10, 3second - 20. And then print a sum of it. (35). Since I'm a very beginner, got stuck with it.

```
int main()

{
    int a,b;
    cout << " Enter a and b: " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i=1; i<=b; i++) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This after cin 3 seconds prints 1,2,3. I tried to sum it with +=i, but i do not get how does it work. How to write a code which tells to count 
n + nx2 + nx2x2 + nx2x2x2.... in a loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Think on how you would do this with a pen and some paper.

Comment: See when I was in school we would draw out two-page big diagrams of how our algorithms were working.

Comment: Bah. You were lucky to have diagrams. In my day we were still banging rocks together to make code.

Comment: I would write a+a*t+a*t*t .... +n . a is a number which gets bigger 2x every new second.

Comment: Rocks?  ROCKS?  Bah, we wish we had rocks.  When we wanted to figure out an algorithm, we had to use kindergarteners.

Comment: With values 5 and 3 for a and b respectively, what is the result you want your program should output? You have given a correct answer for a result = 40. Is that what you want? If so, please modify your question. My answer will print the result as 35 as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a,b,i,result;
    cout << " Enter a and b: " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    result = a;                 // At 0 sec result is a
    for (i=1; i<=b; i++) 
    {
        result = result*2;      // Doubles the result at every second
        cout <<result<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a new variable `result`. Then modify its value depending on your logic.

```
int result = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=b; i++) {
    result = result + a;
    cout << a << endl;
    a = a * 2;
}
cout << result << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well right now you're just printing out the number of times it loops, since you're going from `i=1` to `i=3`. So, your `i`'s values are: 1, 2, 3 when `b = 3`. So how does that relate to the algorithm: 
`a+at+at*t .... +n` 
that you came up with. Find that pattern and use your `a` value.